# Pushing a Functor into a tuple

Tags: haskell

I've simplified the type signature of some code I need, and it looks roughly like this:

```
Functor f => f (Maybe a, b) -> (Maybe (f a), f b)
```

Can I, how do I implement such a function? And if so, how? I'm half guessing I need to push the functor down using `Traversable`, but I'm having trouble putting this all together in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do, if it is Traversable and not Functor.

```
fn :: Traversable t => t (Maybe a, b) -> (Maybe (t a), t b)
fn v = (sequenceA $ fmap fst v, fmap snd v)
```

Is it okay?

Answer (score 5):

Pushing `f` one level down can be done by:

```
fn :: Functor f => f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
fn v = (fmap fst v, fmap snd v)
```

(Note that tuples are not traversable if you want *both* sides.)

The second part is

```
Functor f => f (Maybe a) -> Maybe (f a)
```

This type is only inhabited by `const Nothing`, because the only function you can apply to this value is `fmap`, getting a value of type `f b` for some `b`.

To illustrate why this second part is not possible, consider the fact that `IO` is an instance of `Functor`. If you could get a `Maybe (IO a)` from your value, applying `isJust` to it would leak one bit of information about the original `IO (Maybe a)` value without executing it.

Comment: Some mention of the `Distributive` class, and perhaps `Representable`, seems appropriate.

Comment: @dfeuer that's out of my depth, perhaps elaborate in a separate answer?

Comment: @dfeuer `Distributive` can't help here because `Maybe` isn't `Distributive`. You need `Traversable f`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, `Maybe` not being `Distributive` was my point.

Comment: Ah, we agree then :)